# Apache Tomcat Server won't start after attempting to enable SSL

Tags: java, tomcat

This is my first time working with tomcat and I'm following a guide that supposed to harden tomcat: https://geekflare.com/apache-tomcat-hardening-and-security-guide/. I don't have an SSL certificate but I was told that it can still be enabled.

This is my Connector in the `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               Server =" "
               redirectPort="8443" 
               SSLEnabled="true" 
               maxThreads="150" 
               scheme="https" 
               secure="true"
               clientAuth="false"              
               sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" 
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"
               />
```

If everything after `redirectPort="8443"` is removed the server works, but if not it doesn't start and this error is logged in the log:

```
Element type "Connector" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Comment: "I was told that SSL can still be enabled" [No, you need a certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38592). It can be self-signed (<-search suggestion), but you need one.

Comment: That specific error is an XML parsing error. What you have in the question text above looks okay to me. Maybe it's not exactly the same as in your server.xml? Or maybe you have another `<Connector>` in there that you didn't post?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no that's the only `<Connector>` in the server.xml and it's also the same as you see on here. I don't know maybe I do need a signed certificate for it to work, but then that would make no sense because self-signed certificates can be used for testing purposes. I just have to figure out how to create one.

Comment: Well, something is wrong with your XML. Open that file in an editor that understands XML and look for errors/warnings. Or post it online to the W3C checker... I think that one does XML, too. Your error has nothing to do with Tomcat and everything to do with an XML syntax problem.